# Groupings not copying with rows

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I want to copy rows from sheet 1 to sheet 2. However sheet 1 has grouping levels till 7. the below code is copying all the rows but, it does not copy groupings after level 4. That is, it doesn't show any grouping for level 5, 6, 7.

The code is as below:

```
  srcworkSheet.Activate();
        Assy1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)srcworkSheet.get_Range("A3", "A25").EntireRow;
        Assy1.Select();
        Assy1.Copy(Type.Missing);

        //Copy First Assembly to Sheet 2:
        destworkSheet.Activate();
        destrange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)destworkSheet.Cells[2, 1];
        destrange.Select();
        destworkSheet.Paste(Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the newly created sheet has the

```
_workSheet.Outline.SummaryRow = Excel.XlSummaryRow.(xlSummaryAbove/xlSummaryBelow);
```

set to xlSummaryBelow.This caused the grouping to be disrupted. Changed it to the value which the Source sheet had.